# What is the correct WordPress .htaccess for a blog within two subfolders?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

Let's say you have a WordPress site installed in the www.example.com/folder1/folder2 directory. And let's say you want the site to be displayed as www.example.com/folder1.

What should the .htaccess inside folder1 look like for that to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer. The correct .htaccess config for a situation above would be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder1/folder2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /folder1/folder2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```